# Selectively changing brightness and contrast in GIMP

Tags: gimp, contrast

Thank you very much for answering my previous question. That taught me a number of new techniques, and did a very good job of removing the orange stain and preserving the sepia tone. Now I have another question: How, with GIMP, do I most easily make the area shown in the red outline darker and more contrasty, without changing its colour? I guess that there was either light leaking into the camera, or some error was made whist developing and printing the original photo to create this lighter area. Thank you - Rowan

[image: Area to be enhanced]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahh… this is one where my first thought *does* have an equivalent in Gimp.

[The **Burn** Tool](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-dodge-burn.html)

This is two seconds in Photoshop, Gimp should be similar [more care == better results, of course.]

[image]

Settings were soft brush, Midtones, 100%

Comment: Thank you. I knew there must be a way to do this, but had never penetrated the dodge/burn tool. Thank you - Rowan